# Creating and managing separate heaps using pThreads

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, posix, heap-memory

In this scenario, I have a vector of vectors of unsigned integers which I am processing. In the normal case, there will be 256 vectors of 1048576 unsigned integers. I want to use the pThread c++ API such that each pthread will do the following work on its assigned sub-list of unsigned integers(of length 1048576).

```
for(int i = 0; i < list_size; i++)
{
    int *arg = (int *) malloc(sizeof(*arg));
    *arg = i;
    thread_err = pthread_create(&(threads[i]), NULL, &Heap_Build, arg);
    if (thread_err != 0)
        printf("\nCan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(thread_err));
}
```

As you tell from the above code, I am simply generating as many threads as there are sub-lists in the main list and I'm sending them each with an index value into the main vector of sub-lists so they know which sub-list they are effectively processing.

```
void* Heap_Build(void *arg)
{
   int main_list_index = *((int *)arg);

   //pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex1 );
   num_of_nodes = 0;
   pheapType heap = pheapType(malloc((k+usage_offset) * sizeof(heapType)));
   unsigned int sublist_value;

   for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
   {

     sublist_value = main_list.at(main_list_index).at(i);

     Heap_Insert_Node(heap, sublist_value); 
   }


   for(int i = k; i < sub_list_size; i++)
   {
       sublist_value = main_list.at(main_list_index).at(i);


       if(sublist_value < heap[usage_offset])
       {
          Heap_Update_Key_CPU(heap, 0, sublist_value);
       }
    }
    //pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex1 );
    cpu_results[main_list_index] = heap[usage_offset];
    free(heap);
}
```

Note

- num_of_nodes - Is the number of nodes currently inserted into the heap structure. This is set at 0 before each heap's construction and used by the update_key and insert_node operations to determine the index in the heap array to place the value.
- sublist_value - Is the current value of the sublist being processed.

The above function essentially allocates an array of memory to build a heap from the first 'k' elements in the sub-list that the thread is processing. It then processes the remaining elements, using the heap's update key operation.

So each thread is given an index to a sub-list in a global vector of sub-lists of unsigned integers. It creates a heap from the first kth elements in the sub-list then processes the remaining kth elements in the sub-lists based on that heap which it created.

I can get everything to work fine if I do 2^8 sub-lists of size 2^8 or 256 threads processing 256 sub-lists of 256 integers or even 1 sub-list of 2^20 integers, but in the test case, 2^8 sub-lists of 2^20 integers. The program either has a segmentation fault or simply just aborts.

If I uncomment the mutex locks. Any case works fine, but unfortunately, it would be doing the computation in a serial manner. I'm not sure what the issue may be, mainly because I'm new at dealing with POSIX threads. Obviously, the issue has to deal with number of integers in the sub-list being too great in combination with the number of threads and possibly a race condition but I'm not sure how to identify the critical regions in the overall computation instead of just placing a mutex lock over the entire computation and removing all parallelism.

If needed, I could provide the code for the two heap functions used in the Heap_Build but I'm not trying to bog down this question with too much code.

**EDIT: I believe the problem in the above code is that all threads are referencing the same memory space, 'heap', instead of each thread allocating a heap structure of their own. Therefore when the first thread that finishes the computation frees the space of memory allocated for 'heap', the other threads are referencing an invalid memory area thus the segmentation fault.
If I remove the 'free(heap)' line, the error disappears but the values are incorrect. I'm not sure how to correct this, I think it would require giving each pthread it's own heap memory space to work within so that none of the threads would be stepping on each other's data, but I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this.**

Comment: Please note the section in bold up above.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have shown, each thread running `Heap_Build` function allocates its own heap structure to work with:

```
pheapType heap = pheapType(malloc((k+usage_offset) * sizeof(heapType)));
```

This memory is local to a thread (in the sense that it is not known to other threads, unless shared by some code not shown in the question), thus I think your concern in bold is not valid.

However your code does not check that the memory was really allocated. 256 vectors of 1048576 integers already consume 2^(20+8+2)=2^30, or 1GB, of memory. If the code is 32 bit and the allocation size is significant, it might happen that there is no free memory block of sufficient length. Then, in some thread `heap` can be NULL, and manipulations with such a "heap" will likely result in a crash.

Another possibility is data races in `Heap_Insert_Node` and/or `Heap_Update_Key_CPU`, in case these functions have side effects (e.g. modify some global variables).